# Check docx is corrupted or not

Tags: c#, file, openxml

I tried many solution but code is always checking corrupted file and send true

```
using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(path[0]))
{
    MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
    memStream.SetLength(fileStream.Length);
    fileStream.Read(memStream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)fileStream.Length);

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=myfile.docx");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(memStream.ToArray());
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
   // HttpContext.Current.Response.Close();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
}
```

where path[0] is my docx location..it still read corrupted file and doesnot throw any error..any suggestion plz..

Comment: I'm not clear what the question is here.  Are you downloading an okay file, and discovering that it's always corrupted during download?  Or are you wanting to know how to detect a corrupted file and not download it?

Comment: @Beska after uploading a file I want to check if it is corrupted or not..it's not always corrupted..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look in this page: [How to: Validate a word processing document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb497334.aspx).

Using the [Open XML SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/), you can write a code like this:

```
public static void ValidateWordDocument(string filepath)
{
    using (var wordprocessingDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(filepath, true))
    {                  
        try
        {           
            OpenXmlValidator validator = new OpenXmlValidator();
            int count = 0;
            foreach (ValidationErrorInfo error in
                validator.Validate(wordprocessingDocument))
            {
                count++;
                Console.WriteLine("Error " + count);
                Console.WriteLine("Description: " + error.Description);
                Console.WriteLine("ErrorType: " + error.ErrorType);
                Console.WriteLine("Node: " + error.Node);
                Console.WriteLine("Path: " + error.Path.XPath);
                Console.WriteLine("Part: " + error.Part.Uri);
                Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("count={0}", count);
            }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);              
        }

        wordprocessingDocument.Close();
    }
}
```

But you should also check if the file was really damaged, or your download code isn't ok.

Comment: shows an error in using that `the type 'system.io.packaging.package'is defined in an assemblythat is not referenced`

Comment: solve above error by just adding `windowbase` from add reference `.net` tab

Answer (score 2):

You can use OpenXmlValidator from [OpenXML SDK 2.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124) to validate MS Office documents, like that

```
OpenXmlValidator validator = new OpenXmlValidator();
bool isValid=validator.Validate(WordprocessingDocument.Open("InvalidFile.docx", true)).Count()==0
```

Comment: I have to include .msi in my project??

Comment: No, just install it on your development machine, then add reference to DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll, and set Copy local = true in reference's properties.